# Backup WSO2 DAS CEP event flow and restore in another DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-cep

Is it possible to backup entire CEP event flow at a DAS and restore in a another DAS? If it is how can i do that?

Comment: I am even curious where the event flow is stored...

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Now i am considering to backup entire file system and restore it in a new machine.

Comment: I believe the stream data are stored in the *data* folder and in the database  (I see multiple temporary tables created in the database and there are stream data for sure), however I really don't understand stage or state of the data during the processing..

Comment: Actually i thought stream data are stored somehow in the machine cash memory, because we thought our problem is related with insufficient cash memory. However at the moment i'm not very mach  considering about stream data.

Answer (score 2):

Usually events in the Streams are not persisted out of box. If you need to persist the events you need to configure it in the streams [1]. When you are persisting you need to select a record store, by default it is "EVENT_STORE" which is stored in the H2 database of the pack. H2 database is not recommended for production, where as you need to change the data source to something like mysql database or HBase.

Please refer documentation on setting up MySQL database for more information [2]. If you setup a MySQL database as the source, technically those data could be accessed from another WSO2DAS node.

On the other WSO2DAS supports clustering with multiple nodes. So you can setup a minimum 2 node High Available Cluster with synchronization [3]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Persist+Event+Stream

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Setting+up+MySQL

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Minimum+High+Availability+Deployment+for+WSO2+DAS+3.1.0